# 2d vector incrementation error

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to create a simple minesweeper game, and have some issues with creating the board. I am using a 2d vector in lieu of a 2d array and am having trouble incrementing the tiles value to see how many mines are adjacent to the tile.

```
int Boardsize::createBoard() const {
//  vector < vector<Tile> > board;
impl->board.resize(getLength(), vector<Tile>(getWidth(), Tile()));
for (int i = 0; i < getMines(); i++) {
    int v1 = rand() % getLength();
    int v2 = rand() % getWidth();
    if (impl->board[v1][v2].getMine() == true) i--;
    else  {impl->board[v1][v2].setMine(true);
          if (v1 - 1 > -1) impl->board[v1-1][v2]++;
          if (v1 + 1 < getLength()) impl->board[v1+1][v2]++;
          if (v2 - 1 > -1) impl->board[v1][v2-1]++;
          if (v2 + 1 < getWidth()) impl->board[v1][v2+1]++;
          if ((v1 - 1 > -1) && (v2 - 1 > -1)) impl->board[v1-1][v2-1]++;
          if ((v1 - 1 > -1) && (v2 + 1 < getWidth())) impl->board[v1-1][v2+1]++;
          if ((v1 + 1 < getLength()) && (v2 - 1 > -1)) impl->board[v1+1][v2-1]++;
          if ((v1 + 1 < getLength()) && (v2 + 1 < getWidth())) impl->board[v1+1][v2+1]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Values length, width and mines are set ahead of time. The way I intend it to work is "Check if getMine = true, if yes then game over. If no, isRevealed is set to true and the tile shows how many mines are adjacent to the tile. However, I'm getting the error:

```
error: no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++' [-fpermissive]|
```

Do I need to set a seperate function to increment the content? I am assuming that the board.resize fills the vector full of 0's.
I appreciate the help.

Here is the "Tile" file's contents:

```
namespace Minesweeper {
using namespace std;

class Tile::Tilement {
    int status;
    bool mine;
    int Adjmines;
    friend class Tile;
public:
    Tilement ()
    : status(0), mine(false), Adjmines(0)
    {
    }
};

Tile::Tile() {
    cout << "Tile is being created" << endl;
}
Tile::~Tile() {
    cout << "Tile is being deleted" << endl;
}

void Tile::setMine(int a) {
    tint->mine = true;
}

void Tile::setStatus(int a) {
    if ((a == 0) || (a == 1) || (a == 2)) {
        tint->status = a;
    }
    else {
        #ifdef DEBUG
        cout << "Tile status invalid" << endl;
        #endif // DEBUG
        throw invalid_argument("Invalid tile status");
    }
}

//void Tile::setContent(char r) {
//    tint->content = r;
//}

int Tile::getStatus() const {
    return tint->status;
}

char Tile::getAdjcount() const {
    return tint->Adjmines;
}

char Tile::getMine() const {
    return tint->mine;
}

int Tile::setAdjmines(int a) {
    a = a++;
}

char Tile::getContent() const {
    if (Tile::getMine() == true) {
        return tint->mine;
    }
    else return tint->Adjmines;
}
```

EDIT: I've changed the incrementations a bit so that they're now like this:

```
if (v1 - 1 > -1) impl->board[v1-1][v2].incAdjmines; (etc).
```

And the incAdjmines function looks like this:

```
int Tile::incAdjmines() {
Adjmines = Adjmines + 1;
}
```

And...well, the code *compiled*, if nothing else, but due to some errors in another fragment of code, I can't tell if it works correctly. Thank you all for your help so far.

Comment: Well you *do* try to "call" `Tile::operator++(int)`. What would you expect to happen if you increment an `Tile` object?

Comment: You don't use anything called "isRevealed". Did you intend to write `impl->board[v1-1][v2].isRevealed = true;`?

Comment: @molbdnilo I've simply used the "isRevealed" as an example on how I intend it to work in the end.

Comment: As I told you there is no ++ overloading so you are like calling a member function which is not exist.

Comment: and BTW what is this for "a = a++;" ?!? even if there was an "a" member variable it will not see it. it will consider it as the "a" argument. and just "a++" is enough.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi It's simply a failed attempt at incrementation. It's been removed since.

Comment: @Anstane Good you removed it, because `a = a++` is [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg nice to know that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `++` on `Tile` object which seems with no overload for this operator.
You can solve your problem by overloading this operator for `Tile` class. Or by directly telling which variable you want to increase for example:

```
impl->board[v1-1][v2].cout_of_things++
```